# Sending operator characters like > and < to Docusign text tabs

Tags: docusignapi, special-characters

When I use an API call to create an envelope from a template, the value of the specific field is shown like this:
> 5,000,000 while it's is being sent like "> 5,000,000" in the request JSON!
So, instead of "> 5,000,000" the user will see "> 5,000,000".

I would appreciate any suggestion on this.
TIA

I create the request JSON and I send it through an API call to create the envelope like other envelopes but this one has a text field containing "> 5,000,000" so the node is like this:
"Value":"> 5,000,000"

Comment: instead of "> 5,000,000" the user will see "> 5,000,000"
I see two identical strings inside the double quotes. Can you explain how they are different? what character is different?

Answer (score 0):

I just tried this and it worked just fine, not seeing any issues with the string "> 5,000,000" or with using the > character. If you have JSON encoded, make sure that > is not encoded or not being used as part of encoding of the JSON. Otherwise, it's a string inside quotes and can be anything you want.

Comment: I really appreciate your respond.  
The issue was solved just this morning before your respond.  
I just recognized that the issue for showing "Greater/Less Than" characters is just visible on the DocuSign preview page of the envelope but when it's sent to the recipients, everything is just fine on their side.  
So, the (> &gt; ) could be ignored on the preview page and the actual envelope will be fine.  
But thank you again for your quick respond, it's much appreciated.